# Strange error "403 Forbidden" for files in public/images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline

I have got strange error - "403 Forbidden" for images in directory `public/images` . But other images from nested directories loads without problems (i.g. from `public/images/product` ).  I'm using Nginx + passenger + capistrano. In production.rb I have `config.serve_static_assets = true` .
Maybe error in assets pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions for the folder? As in right-click -> properties or 'chmod' to '755'?

Comment: Mine as well, although it's about a PHP app, not rails. Thank you.